# Fatal Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, composer-php, phalcon

I'm trying to run "/vendor/bin/phalcon-migrations run" but I keep getting this error message:
Fatal Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

config.php:

```
return new Config([
    'database' => [
        'adapter' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'dbname' => 'admin',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.3",
    "ext-phalcon": "^4.0.6",
    "phalcon/migrations": "^2.2",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^6.2"
  }
```

the system is ubuntu i tried running the migration on super-user mode but i am getting the same error if anyone can help me solve this problem im kinda new to all of this

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem all i had to do was to log in the database and write the next command:

use admin

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

(but i am not sure why this changed my password to root (the user too i think)

Comment: You connect without a password, and adding a user root  with password 'root' solved the problem?

Comment: yes after running the code above in terminal i changed the config.php connection added a user root with password root solved the problem i was able to run migration after that without a problem